# PHP CURL to external file load class

Tags: php, api, class, curl

I have a api file which looks:

```
<?php
class Api {
    public static function instance() {
        if ( ! self::$_instance )
            self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> sessionId = [...];
        $this -> login();
    }

    private function __clone() {}
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to execute this class by api call or i have to make an additional file which will execute this file with API and uses this class ?

Comment: A class definition by itself is not executable, it's a simply a declaration of a structure. You have to have some code which creates an instance of the class and/or calls a static method of the class. And yes you could, if you wished, make that code accessible so it can be executed by making a HTTP request - that's basically how all web-based PHP applications work after all. So you need some more code, but probably only a line or two extra (for a really basic demo)

Comment: Off topic but if this class is meant to be a singleton, it should have a private constructor